# Template in Django not found

Tags: django, pycharm

In the code below, my problem is that template file 'UserAccount' is not found. I set the app in the settings and create a directory in the app and an html file in the directory.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'UserAccount/login.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be your settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # django essentials
    "django.contrib.admin",
    ...

    # my apps
    "myapp",   #the app name is "myapp"
]

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("template"))], # change this line in your settings
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

now create a directory in the same directory as your apps. sth like this:

```
myapp
app_two
template
...
```

now in template directory create another directory with the name of your app. in tha t put your `html` fiels. like this:

```
| myapp
| app_two
| template
|----myapp
     |----sth.html
     |----sth_2.html
|----app_two
```

now when you want to reference them do it like this:

```
return render(request, 'myapp/sth.html', context)
```

General tips on asking question on Stackoverflow:

1. for title : a summary of your problem with keywords like "django" or "django-views"
2. for putting your code use three backticks --> `code`
3. search a lot before asking question. there is a huge chance that someone had posted the same problem before you and you can find your answer there